# Randomly "502 bad gateway" on production, but it's ok on dev machine (express js)

Tags: node.js, express, curl, libcurl, linode

I've got a node js script (Express js framework). I have a problem with this server only on production - on developer machine everything is good.

On developer machine an on production this server is running in Docker container. Container if from the same image of course.

The problematic scenario:

1. Start server
2. Make a request:

   2.1. upload file to server and save in on hard disc drive

   2.2. send a POST request via curl to microservice. This request is send to micorservice the file from 2.1 point. It's POST request. We use node-libcurl library

   2.3. After long time (few minutes) microservice returns a response.

   2.4. This response is saved on server.

   2.5. Print a template.

On developer machine this request works totally correctly: from point 2.1 to 2.5.

But on production machine this request works correctly do all points except 2.5. I know it works good on 2.1-2.4 because server logs this information.

Production is on https://www.linode.com/.

Have you any idea what's wrong?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, but server on production returns "502 bad gateway" error randomly for the same file and microservice response. Sometimes this requests is ok

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you start the application within the container, but I would suggest you'll use forever (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to make sure it does not go inactive.

I've had 502 errors because of that in other systems when there were no activity for a few minutes.

Hope this helps a little